# why does $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z^2$ not a covering map with the point $z = 0$ included?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I just learned the basic concept of the covering map. In the wolfram page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoveringMap.html, it says that $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z^2$ is not a covering map with the point $z = 0$ included. I'm not sure how to prove it. Can someone explain to me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma**: Given any open set $U$ of $\mathbb C$ containing $0$, there exist $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ such that $z\in U$ and $-z\in U$.

**Proof**: If $U$ is open, then so is $V=\{v\mid -v\in U\}$. Then $U\cap V$ is open. $U\cap V$ is not empty, since $0\in U\cap V$. Singletons are not open in $\mathbb C$, so $U\cap V$ must contain a non-zero element, $z$, and $z\in U$ and $-z\in U$.

---

From this we see the problem - given any open neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there is a pair of values $z,-z\in U$, so $f(z)=f(-z)$ and so $f$ is not one-to-one, and thus not a homeomorphism on any open neighborhood of $0$. So $f$ is not a covering map.

Comment: Hi, your argument makes a lot of sense, but I'm confused by your notation of z and x...could you make them all z or all x?

Comment: Whoops, tried to replace all $x$s with $z$, and failed. @Sandy.Davidson Fixed

Comment: Great! Thanks! And I can extend the same argument to $f(z) = z^n$ right? Given any open neighborhood U of 0, there are n values in U that $f(z_1) = f(z_2) = .... = f(z_n)$. So f is not one-to-one and thus not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes. In that case, you'd need a $n$th root of unit, $\zeta_n$ and then $V=\{v\mid \zeta_n v\in U\}$. You don't need to show all $n$ of the $z_i$ go to the same value, just two of them.

Answer (score 1):

If $p:E \to B$ is a covering map with $B$ connected, the cardinal of the fiber $f^{-1}(b)$ is constant.

Comment: Seems like overkill to use a general theorem when first introduced to covering spaces and specifically when told the OP is just learning the definition...

Comment: It's not that overkill. If $U$ is a good connected neighborhood of $b$ (i.e as the definition, then $f$  restricts to an homeo to each of the component of $f^{-1}(U)$. In particular the set $B_{\alpha} = \{ b \in B, f^{-1}(b)$ has cardinal $\alpha \}$ form a partition of $U$.